# Wordpress how to get specific post data using WP_REST_Posts_Controller

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

How I can get specific post data in foreach loop? (only title for example)

Here is my PHP (returns all post data):

```
function myspace_get_posts_by_tag(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    
    $slug = $request['slug'];
    $page = $request['page'];

    $term = get_term_by('slug', $slug, 'post_tag');
    $posts_per_page = 1;

    $args = array(
        'tag__in'           => $term->term_id,
        'posts_per_page'    => $posts_per_page,
        'paged'             => $page,
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'desc',
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    $max_pages = $query->max_num_pages;
    $total = $query->found_posts;

    $posts = $query->posts;

    $controller = new WP_REST_Posts_Controller('post');

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

        $response = $controller->prepare_item_for_response( $post, $request );
        $data[] = $controller->prepare_response_for_collection( $response );            

    }
   
    $response = new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
    $response->header( 'X-WP-Total', $total ); 
    $response->header( 'X-WP-TotalPages', $max_pages );
    return $response;
    
}
```

I cut down some code just for the sake of example.

Comment: Wouldn't $post->post_title work? (in the foreach loop)

Comment: Yeah it works:  `$data["posts"][] = array( "id" => $post->ID, "title" => $post->post_title );` Get rid of: //$response = $controller->prepare_item_for_response( $post, $request ); //$data[] = $controller->prepare_response_for_collection( $response ) ?

Comment: Cool. If it helped may I add it as an answer for your approval?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can add it

Comment: Great, added it, I will appreciate if you'd accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to fetch the posts later in the foreach loop.

In that case, $post is a [WP_Post Object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/). So you can access its properties, in your case - the post's title:

```
$post->post_title
```